# How to implement LAR patch in ns2?

Tags: ns2

I am new to Network Simulator (NS2).
I want to simulate Location Aided Routing Protocol over ns2.34 or 2.35.
I have installed ns-allinone-2.35 and have LAR-DREAM Patch file for ns2.35.

**HOW TO INSTALL PATCH?**

I tried
  #patch -p1 < LAR-DREAM.patch

but it says no such file or directory. Placed patch file under ns-allinone-2.35 folder.

Do reply!

Comment: The condition for $ `patch p0 < [patch-name].patch` is a copy of the patch inside ns-allinone-2.35/. ... Note : The default ns2 build directory is like /home/[name]/ns2/ , and all commands must be done as unprivileged user. No root or sudo, please. Except for # `cp ns[name] /usr/local/bin/`

Answer (score 0):

ns-2.35 + LAR and DREAM :

```
tar xvf ns-allinone-2.35_gcc482.tar.gz
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNSGJCZ2YzUGJDVk0/view?usp=sharing

```
cd ns-allinone-2.35/
patch -p0 < LAR-dream__ns235.patch
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNdVlhckRMMTcxalk/view?usp=sharing

```
./install
cd ns-2.35/
cp ns ns235-lar
sudo cp ns235-lar /usr/local/bin/
```

Simulation : `ns235-lar box-Helen.tcl`, etc. examples from 'lar+dream-examples-0714.tar.gz'  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNbG9DOW1tZXk1d1E/view?usp=sharing